# data migration from mysql to mongodb, i have issue with convergion between IDs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, data-migration

I'm making data migration from MySQL to MongoDB and it's my first time, I followed these steps:-

1. select all data from SQL in the specific table and save it in one `.CSV` file.
2. set headers to the file data so every object has a key.
3. import the `.csv` file to DB using MongoDB compass.

**the problem is** the IDs in SQL away different from the MongoDB objectId, so how can I handle this?

---

note that the old database "SQL" has primary and foreign keys and my MongoDB schema has references too using objetcId. [image: sql id VS MongoDB objectId]

Comment: mongodb does not use auto increment for it's id by default. You need to read this https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment  it is recommended to restructure your data to use mongodb's objectId to avoid data duplication https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: i know mongo doesn't detect and created id by default, but i have this idea to write script that will read .csv files and convert every id to objectId, does id right??

Comment: @mohamedgamal: yes, if you pre-convert ids, it should work just fine.

Comment: "If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId() for the document before inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field, but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or application does not. " https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/